# Using aggregate in MongoDB 3.2 with $lookup to match based on an array of values

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB 3.2 document in a collection called `foos`. The document looks like this:

```
{
  _id: "foo1",
  fooProp: "some prop"
  barKey: ["key1","key2"]
}
```

I want to use the `aggregate` function with `$lookup` to join this document with two other documents in another collection called `bars` by their `barKey` field. These two documents look like this:

```
{
  _id: "bar1",
  barKey: "key1",
  barProp: "some prop 2"
},
{
  _id: "bar2",
  barKey: "key2",
  barProp: "some prop 3"
}
```

So the strings in the `barKey` array of the `foo` document each match to a `bar` document with the same `barKey` value.

**Initially, I was using MongoDB 3.4**, and I was able to use this simple query to get the desired result:

```
//mongo 3.4 query (working)

db.foos
  .aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "bars",
        localField: "barKey",
        foreignField: "barKey",
        as: "barData"
      }
    }
  ])
```

The result (which is the **ideal result**) looked like:

```
//mongo 3.4 ideal result

{
  _id: "foo1",
  fooProp: "some prop"
  barKey: ["key1","key2"],
  barData: [
    {
      _id: "bar1",
      barKey: "key1",
      barProp: "some prop 2"
    },
    {
      _id: "bar2",
      barKey: "key2",
      barProp: "some prop 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**However, in MongoDB 3.2**, this same query results in an empty array `[]` for `barData`.

I added an `$unwind` step for the `barKey` array:

```
//mongo 3.2 query (partly working)

db.foos
  .aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$bldgKey" },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "bars",
        localField: "barKey",
        foreignField: "barKey",
        as: "barData"
      }
    }
  ])
```

...which partly works, but now the result has duplicate documents from the `foos` collection for each document in the `bars` collection, instead of nesting the `bars` documents within a single `foos` document:

```
//mongo 3.2 less-than-ideal result

{
  _id: "foo1",
  fooProp: "some prop"
  barKey: ["key1","key2"],
  barData: [
    {
      _id: "bar1",
      barKey: "key1",
      barProp: "some prop 2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: "foo1",
  fooProp: "some prop"
  barKey: ["key1","key2"],
  barData: [
    {
      _id: "bar2",
      barKey: "key2",
      barProp: "some prop 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**What's the best way in Mongo 3.2 to get the ideal result that I got in Mongo 3.4 using a simpler query?**

If I use `$group`, I would prefer to not have to list out every field that I want in the result, and just grab all of them from the document agnostically if possible. The foo-bar example I've given here is a simplified example of real-world documents that each contain dozens of different fields that can vary from document to document.